# Finding a text string yyyymm based on current year and month

Tags: excel, vba

I need to locate all cells within column L starting from Row 10 containing yyyymm+2 (202009).
In other words, I'm looking for cells containing all dates belonging to the month 2 months in advance of the current month. Valid values would be 20200901 up until 20200930 accordingly as of July 2020.

The Column L contains values in text format such as 20201120, 20210102, etc. All the values are dates in Column L formatted as text as 'yyyymmdd'.

I'm trying to use the code below, but it is quite clearly wrong, since +2 won't show the correct year or month if the year changes.

```
Dim strSearchText As String
Dim y As Integer
Dim m As Integer
m = DatePart("mm", Date) + 2
y = DatePart("yyyy", Date)
strSearchText = y & m
Dim rngSearchArea As Range
Set rngSearchArea = ws.Range(Range("L10"), ws.Range("L" & ws.Range("L:L").Cells.Count).End(xlUp))
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: How and where to return the processed cells range? But, are you sure that the dates in discussion are formatted like string? For instance, if you put a formula like `=Day(L2)` what does it return?

Comment: It doesn't return anything. (You've entered too few arguments). So, yes, these aren't dates.

Comment: How to not return anything? If it would be a string, it should return "NUM!". If it would be a date, it will return its day, or zero if nothing in that cell... Do you have one of your above mentioned range (like 20200901) in "L2"? Oh... Now I can see that your range starts from row 10. So change it in `=Day(L11)`.

Comment: It returns #NUM!

Comment: So, please test my code answer. It will do what you need. The processing result will be dropped in column N:N, starting from the tenth row... Please, confirm that it does what (I understood) you need.

Answer (score 1):

Please test the next code. Since you did not answer my above question, it will return the range of processed dates in the column N:N, starting from the tenth row:

```
Sub GetDateTwoMonthMore()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, arrF As Variant, lastRow As Long
 Dim El As Variant, k As Long, currMonth As Long
 
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("L" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  currMonth = CLng(Month(Date))   'the current month reference
  arr = sh.Range("L10:L" & lastRow).Value 'load the range to be processed in an array
  ReDim arrF(1 To UBound(arr, 1)) 'Redim the final array at the initial dimension of all the range rows
  For Each El In arr
    If CLng(Mid(El, 5, 2)) = currMonth + 2 Then
    'If CLng(Month(El)) = currMonth + 2 Then 'if your cells are date formatted...
        k = k + 1: arrF(k) = El 'fill the final array with the appropriate dates
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve arrF(k) 'Keep only the non empty array elements
  'Drop the array content in the columnn N:N, at once:
  sh.Range("N10").Resize(UBound(arrF)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrF)
End Sub
```

If your L:L range is Date formatted, you must only comment/delete the line

```
If CLng(Mid(El, 5, 2)) = currMonth + 2 Then
```

and un-comment the next one...

Comment: @smgrd: This only could mean that the analyzed cell does not have a number starting from the fifth character plus the next. Moving the cursor over the `El` when the code stops on error, what does it show? Try, please, fill down the above recommended formula (`=Day(L10)` to the last row with data in column L:L). Does it also return #NUM! for all the range?

Comment: @smgrd: Still alive? Can you answer my above question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm working with other stuff not related to code, so I'm slow to respond. The El shows the last cell formatted as text. The formatting is actually General for all the 'dates' in column L. The header is formatted as text and that's what shows up.

Comment: @smgrd: Very difficult to understand something relevant... Does this 'last cell` contain the same type of string to be processed? If not, do you have the header at the end of the range? I cannot get it... :) If this is the case, try changing of `arr = sh.Range("L10:L" & lastRow)` with `arr = sh.Range("L10:L" & lastRow - 1)`. Or you are trying to say that your range starts from the eleventh row and on the tenth a header does exist?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are just looking for something like that?
String containing today + 2 months in the yyyydd format:

```vb
str = Format(DateAdd("m", 2, Now()), "yyyymm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting and finding the current date into text, it is more accurate to convert the data of cells based on the current date to date data to compare.

```
Sub testDate()

    Dim y As Integer, y1 As String
    Dim m As Integer, m1 As String, d1 As String
    Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date
    Dim TargetDay As Date
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    
    y = Year(Date)
    m = Month(Date)
    
    sDate = DateSerial(y, m + 2, 1)
    eDate = DateSerial(y, m + 3, 0) 'Last day
    
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range(Range("L10"), .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    For Each rng In rngDB
        y1 = Left(rng, 4)
        m1 = Mid(rng, 5, 2)
        d1 = Right(rng, 2)
        TargetDay = DateSerial(y1, m1, d1)
        If TargetDay >= sDate And TargetDay <= eDate Then
            Debug.Print rng.Address(0, 0, xlA1)
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```